# import classes? is it nesecarry?

Tags: actionscript-3

why import classes if they work even if you don't?

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var circle1:Sprite = new Sprite();
circle1.graphics.beginFill(0xFFCC00);
circle1.graphics.drawCircle(40, 40, 40);
circle1.buttonMode = true;
circle1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);
```

why are we ment to import classes if the code is working anyways? if the two import lines are escaped the code will still be working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code is compiled as strict, it needs those imports. Unless the instances are decalred as fully qualified class names.

e.g.

```
var circle1:flash.display.Sprite = new flash.display.Sprite();
```

Which I'm sure you don't want to do ;)

I'd always recommend compiling in strict mode anyway, and making sure that your code is properly typed and has the required references (imports).

Comment: ok.. and then I will also have to ask you about this ;) why do you have to write the type after an object or variable? var my_string:String... hehe.. I just think it's a waste of time.. if it works just fine without.. I'm coming from PHP and I think thats alot easier to write (faster)

Comment: @user555222 AS3 is a strongly type language, therefore declaring the object type is an essential language feature, it's part of the design. You can decide to omit it if you wish but that's going again the language paradigm...